# Unable to fetch an sqlite record

Tags: android, sqlite, fetch

I am using the following **query** to fetch a row with a particular **mid**.

```
Cursor mCursor =  mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, "actionData", "mid" }, "mid" + "=" + mid, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I however get an `sqlite` exception when I try to do the same. Any ideas?

The exception is -

```
 Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: qVEl3: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, actionData, mid FROM notifs WHERE mid=qVEl3
```

Comment: all those columns are definitely in there. It works fine when I try to retrieve all columns using return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, "actionData", "mid" }, null, null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the quotations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT _id, actionData, mid FROM notifs WHERE mid='qVEl3'
```

So your Android code should be :

```
Cursor mCursor =  mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
    { KEY_ROWID, "actionData", "mid" }, 
    "mid=?", new String[] {mid}, null, null, null, null);
```

(that will prevent SQL injection too)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use query parameters to avoid issues with quotes:

```java
Cursor mCursor =  mDb.query(
    true,
    DATABASE_TABLE,
    new String[] { KEY_ROWID, "actionData", "mid" }, 
    "mid = ?",              // the ? is a placeholder.
    new String[] { mid },   // sqlite will put the value of mid into the placeholder above.
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
```